# Number of largest element exchanges for quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm improving my algorithms knowledge reading Robert Sedgewick "Algorithms" book and completing exercises. There's the one I have difficulties with:

> What is the maximum number of times during the execution of Quick.sort()
>   that the largest item can be exchanged, for an array of length N ?

I have determined experimentally, that the maximum number of exchanges of the largest item is `floor(N/2)`, assuming all elements in array are distinct. **How do I prove this mathematically? If I'm wrong, what's my mistake?**

I have found several mentions of this question (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742732/scenarios-for-selection-sort-insertion-sort-and-quick-sort)), however, the answers do not match my results. That answers suggest the maximum number is `N-1`, but *I wasn't able to find such an array, that will give me exactly `N-1` exchanges of its largest item, when sorting it with my quicksort version* (see below).

The code of quicksort that I use:

```
template<typename BiDirIterator, typename Compare = std::less<typename BiDirIterator::value_type>>
BiDirIterator partition(BiDirIterator begin, BiDirIterator end, Compare compare = Compare())
{
    auto partition_item = begin;
    while (true)
    {
        while (++begin != end && !compare(*partition_item, *begin));
        while (begin != end && !compare(*--end, *partition_item));

        if (begin == end)
            break;

        std::iter_swap(begin, end);
    }

    if (partition_item != --begin)
        std::iter_swap(partition_item, begin);

    return begin;
}

template<typename BiDirIterator, typename Compare = std::less<typename BiDirIterator::value_type>>
void quicksort(BiDirIterator begin, BiDirIterator end, Compare compare = Compare())
{
    if (begin == end || std::next(begin) == end)
        return;

    auto pos = partition(begin, end, compare);
    quicksort(begin, pos, compare);
    quicksort(++pos, end, compare);
}
```

And the code that I used to calculate the number of exchanges for the lasgest item:

```
struct exchange_counter
{
    exchange_counter(int value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

    int value;
    int number_of_exchanges = 0;

    exchange_counter(const exchange_counter& other) = default;
    exchange_counter& operator=(const exchange_counter& other) = default;
    exchange_counter(exchange_counter&& other) = default;

    exchange_counter& operator=(exchange_counter&& other)
    {
        value = other.value;
        number_of_exchanges = other.number_of_exchanges + 1;
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator<(const exchange_counter& left, const exchange_counter& right) noexcept
    {
        return left.value < right.value;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const exchange_counter& left, const exchange_counter& right) noexcept
    {
        return left.value == right.value;
    }
};

for (int i = 1; i != 15; ++i)
{
    std::vector<exchange_counter> values;
    for (int j = 0; j != i; ++j)
        values.emplace_back(j);

    auto max_element = i - 1;
    auto max_number_of_exchanges = 0;
    do
    {
        for (auto& value : values)
            value.number_of_exchanges = 0;

        auto copy = values;
        quicksort(copy.begin(), copy.end());
        max_number_of_exchanges = (std::max)(max_number_of_exchanges,
            std::find(copy.begin(), copy.end(), max_element)->number_of_exchanges);
    }
    while (std::next_permutation(values.begin(), values.end()));

    std::cout << "Elements: " << i << "; max exchanges: " << max_number_of_exchanges << std::endl;
}
```

PS. If I test `std::sort` in Visual Studio 2015 (which is implemented as quicksort) using the same method, the number of exchanges of the largest item is `N - 1`.

Comment: Presumably an element could be moved on *every* recursive call.  And for a pathological input vector, there could be a call depth of N-1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scenarios for selection sort, insertion sort, and quick sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742732/scenarios-for-selection-sort-insertion-sort-and-quick-sort)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `std::sort` is never **just** a quicksort, it's usually something like introsort.

Comment: I'm looking at the code given in Algorithms 4th edition, and yours is not exactly the same. It might be equivalent. This is for you to prove: have you tested if your code actually correctly sorts the permutations you're generating?

Comment: Yes, I've tested this code on different arrays, it does work. However yes, it may not be exatcly the same as the one in the book. I'm programming in C++ and using iterators, not arrays and indices. I'm trying to solve the question from the book in relation to my quicksort version.

Comment: The best would be to test on the permutations you generate: this would be  close to exhaustive (excluding equal values). I strongly suspect an implementation bug somewhere, but I guess it could also be because of a slightly different approach.

Comment: I've just tested the code with all possible permutations for arrays from 1 to 11 elements. The algorithm works correctly, each array becomes sorted after calling `quicksort` and contains the same elements as the original array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The largest item must be moved by 2 positions each time we partition the array in order to exchange it the maximum number of times. It cannot be moved by just 1 position, because in this case it will become a pivot element and will be moved to its final position. For example, consider the following array:

```
4 10 3 x x x ...
P i  j
```

After partitioning the array the largest element (10) is moved by 1 position to the right

```
3 4 10 x x x ...
    P
```

But now the largest item becomes a pivot element and will be moved to the end of the array, adding only 1 exchange.

Instead, we need to arrange the items so that the largest item is moved by 2 positions keeping 1 item in front to become a pivot element:

```
2 10 4 1 x x x ...
P i    j
```

After partitioning:

```
1 2 4 10 x x x ...
    P i    j
```

The largest item is moved every time by 2 positions, therefore the number of exchanges is floor(N/2).

Example (N = 10)

```
2 10 4 1 6 3 8 5 7 9
```

The maximum number of times that the largest item (10) is exchanged is 5 in this case.

Comment: Brilliant! For others: if you want a maximum exchange, then you would like to put the largest number as left as possible, position 0 fails so starts from position 1. Also for maximum exchange, you would like the largest number to move as slow as possible from left to right, 1 fails as described and 2 is achievable.

Comment: Thanks. Given a sequence of distinct number, arrange the sequence as
`= M ? < > > > > ... >`
where `=` is key, `M `is maximum value, `?` is to be picked, `<` is a value less than the key, `>` is a value larger than the key. Then it will satisfies the move-by-2 arrangement.

start with `= M ? < > > > > ... >`
after first iteration it becomes `=< ? M > > > .. >`
remove the left part we have `? M > > > ... >` 
reiterate ... pick a new key that satisfies `= M ? > > ...>`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer for the question is not accurate. The maximum number cannot be passed over more times than there are spaces available, since it should always be approaching its right position. So, going from being the first to the last value spot, it would be exchanged N times.
There is an one exclusion for this case, and that is when the array has size 1, the largest element can't be moved any more, so the maximum number of moves would be N - 1.

This answer was provided already before in here: [Scenarios for selection sort, insertion sort, and quick sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742732/scenarios-for-selection-sort-insertion-sort-and-quick-sort)

Comment: Then why do my experiments with the algorithm I developed show that the number is `N/2`?

Comment: @dragondreamer because the worst case is quite pathological and occurs only extremely rarely

Comment: @dragondreamer anyhow, by experimenting you can only find a lower bound for the maximum, but unless you try all possible cases you cannot be sure that it is the maximum

Comment: @tobi303 Could you give me an example of an array, say, of six elements, that will give me exactly five exchanges of its largest element when sorting it using my quicksort version?

Comment: If the largest is the first element of the array and the pivot is the second largest, you would finish with n-1 movements

Comment: My quicksort version always uses the first element of an array as a pivot element. My question is still unanswered.